# Query performance with Left Join vs Inner Join - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I wanted to know the difference between the 2 queries.I have 2 tables: Users and Emails.

```
User schema - id, name, email, is_subscribed, created, modified.

Email schema - id, user_id, sent_at, subject.
```

So I need to find the count those users, **who have received a total of more than 20 emails throughout.**

User table has roughly around **100K records**. And Emails table have nearly **4 million records**

**1st Query**

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, count(u.id)
FROM emails as e
LEFT JOIN users as u
ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.is_subscribed = 1
GROUP BY e.user_id HAVING count(u.id) > 20
```

**2nd Query**

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, count(u.id)
FROM users as u
INNER JOIN emails as e
ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.is_subscribed = 1
GROUP BY e.user_id HAVING count(u.id) > 20
```

What I have tried:

1)On production, these query takes like forever to execute, so on local, I have created sample table with dummy records. i.e

**User table - around 5 records and Emails table around 100 records.**

When I execute the above two queries **I get the same result set for both the queries** and when checked for Profiling, I get the same execution time for both queries(which may be different on production) so it is hard to know which is the better one. (This may not be the optimal way to find the solution.)

2)Used Explain with the query, and it shows it scans all **100 rows of emails table** in both the cases(queries)

Please let me know if I have missed any specifics. I will update the question.

Comment: Switch to `...LEFT JOIN users as u
ON e.user_id = u.id
AND u.is_subscribed = 1 GROUP BY...`, to get true left join result. (With a right side table condition in the WHERE clause, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: The better one depends on what you're trying to achieve. In this case, because you know you want to exclude users with no emails (0 is less than 20), an INNER JOIN is more appropriate

Comment: #1: You don't need a LEFT JOIN #2: Try to `GROUP BY u.id HAVING count(*) > 20` instead

Comment: Please read about [mcve]s. Eg: Re " takes like forever to execute", appropriate index are important but we don't know whether you have them. Nor have you given us much other relevant info. Eg: Which version of MySQL? That affects your use of GROUP BY.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Read about [MySQL `LEFT JOIN` optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html). The DBMS can tell that your `LEFT JOIN`s `WHERE` is filtering out all the NULL-extended rows that come from `LEFT JOIN` that don't come from `INNER JOIN` so it just does an `INNER JOIN`.

> MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual
>   9.2.1.9 LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN Optimization
>
> For a LEFT JOIN, if the WHERE condition is always false for the generated NULL row, the LEFT JOIN is changed to a normal join.

(Since you don't want NULL-extended rows, why would you use `LEFT JOIN`?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:-

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, count(u.id)
FROM users as u
INNER JOIN emails as e ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.is_subscribed = 1
GROUP BY u.id 
HAVING count(u.id) > 20
```